# Chatter REST body for leaving a group

Tags: rest-api, chatter

Anyone have an example of how to leave a chatter group via the REST API?  I can successfully join a chatter group via the api with the example below, but I see no documentation on the body of the POST request to **leave** a group.

`/chatter/groups/0F9D00000000I4O/members?userId=005D0000001LLO1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send a DELETE HTTP request to salesforce API

```
/chatter/group-memberships/membershipId
```

Also note that membershipId you have to get via API first .This is a junction record between group and the User record.The below will get you membershipIds for all members of the particular Group

```
/services/data/v34.0/chatter/groups/0F990000000bt8E/members
```

Where the HardCoded Id is your GroupId and this will give you all group memembers

This is document [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_group_memberships.htm?search_text=Group%20membership#cc_group_mem_info)

Comment: Appreciate it!  Worked just like you said.  Thanks.